# Body Scanner in UAE?

Tags: uae, x-ray-machines

Do they have human xray or body scanner in  UAE specifically in Dubai? (I don't know how to call it)

Do they search thoroughly your body?

Comment: A metal detector ? When you say search do you mean manually ?

Comment: Do you mean a Metal Detector, a Manual Search, or a Terrahertz/Millimeter wave imaging system? (AFAIK, nowhere is operating the extremely hazardous practice of routinely xraying passengers)

Comment: Are you trying to smuggle something in (please don't, they can punish people severely), or worried about them seeing your naked body?

Comment: @pnuts Well, Dubai International Airport (DXB) serves about 78 million passengers a year, whereas Al Maktoum (DWC) serves about 800,000. Clarification from the asker would be good but, on the balance of probabilities, they're asking about DXB

Answer (score 2):

According to what I found online:

- From [EUROPE1](http://www.europe1.fr/international/dubai-aeroports-pas-de-scanner-corporel-229941) : Dubaï has not put in place body scanner in both their airports because it is against Islam, and individuals intimacy. 
  Scanners are replaced by other inspection systemps like the following :
- [«Smart border project» and «Finger On the Fly»](http://www.lefigaro.fr/conjoncture/2015/01/29/20002-20150129ARTFIG00274-les-emirats-installent-l-aeroport-du-futur.php) is how they check passengers identity through biometric check. It is more acceptable for passengers to be checked since womens don't have to remove their veil

Comment: That first link is 6 years old though

Comment: @blackbird true, although they are talking about the strategy that they were going to adopt for Dubaï airports, strategy that took a lot of thinking before it was put in place and it most likely still in place. The second link is from 2015 and talks about the same thing. I did not translate it because I thought all of it would not be relevant but you can still check